# IF and LEFT JOIN do not work

Tags: mysqli, left-join

I have simple mysql query:

```
SELECT product.user_id, product.type, product.body, product.created, product.id, product.url, product.name, product.price, images.src 
FROM xn_product AS product 
LEFT JOIN xn_images AS images ON product.id = images.item_id 
WHERE product.active = '1' AND images.type = 'product' AND product.promoted = '1' AND images.main = '1' AND product.url = '". $url "'
```

And I have problem. When in images.table dont't have product.id query is not executed. I tried to do something with IF and IF NULL but without success.

I want to see if it is empty images.src to overwrite them as 'empty.jpg' OR 1

Answer (score 0):

Try using an INNER join

```
SELECT product.user_id, product.type, product.body, product.created, product.id, product.url, product.name, product.price, images.src 
FROM xn_product AS product 
INNER JOIN xn_images AS images ON product.id = images.item_id 
WHERE product.active = '1' AND images.type = 'product' AND product.promoted = '1' AND images.main = '1' AND product.url = '". $url ."'
```

Comment: The problem  "WHERE" I change it for AND and working properly, and give only for AND product.url = '". $url "' WHERE :)